tmux kubectl port-forward error message persisting
I recently ran the following command:
kubectl port-forward kubia-manual 8888:8080

after creating the following pod in my cluster:
apiVersion: v1

kind: Pod

metadata:
  name: kubia-manual
spec:
  containers:
  - image: luksa/kubia
    name: kubia
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080

      protocol: TCP

the command was successful and I had a kube-proxy running at my localhost and working as expected.
However, after deleting all resources:
kubectl delete all --all

followed by a cluster stop:
minikube stop

I was given the following message:
E0519 08:31:17.077543  230977 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

which I'm assuming has something to do with the fact that there is some mechanism somewhere still attempting this connection. I did run
kubectl delete all --all

which I'm assuming should've deleted the resource but I'm not sure why it's persisted.
What's even more interesting is that this is specifically related to tmux as exiting the tmux session hides the error and entering a new tmux session shows the error again
Any ideas?
